# Issue with %date% and %time% on the command line

Tags: windows, variables, cmd

I got this command to generate a log file that contains the date in the name.

echo %time%;stuff done >> C:\myfile_%date%.log

Output:
The system cannot find the path specified.

If I do remove the system variable, all fine.
I have attempted to add "" and `` and '', no go so far.

Some help would be welcome :)
Thanks.

Comment: Does it break when you just remove the %date%?

Comment: All is fine. Meaning that the file is correctly created with my echo values inside. If I run: echo %date% I got the correct date.

Comment: The %date% variable has spaces in it which im sure is causing some problems.  I get "myfile_Mon" when I run the command

Comment: Here is my output: C:\>echo %date%
16/06/2014

C:\>echo %time%;stuff done >> C:\myfile_%date%.log
The system cannot find the path specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to generate a date without spaces in it. %date% outputs `Mon 16/06/2014` which when passed as a filename causes problems with the creation. If you substring each of the date elements and build a custom filename with the below:

```
echo %time%;stuff done >> C:\myfile_%date:~10%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%.log
```

your command will work.  The filename I get as a result is:

```
myfile_201416062105.log
```

which as a backwards timestamp will also make them easier to sort and find after the generation.

Comment: Thank you! I have set the date format being part of my script; work nicely now. Really good one :) Thank you. set mydate=%date:~6,4%%date:~3,2%%date:~0,2%
echo %mydate% echo %time%;stuff done >> C:\myfile_%mydate